# RDLC - Hidden Columns, which one expands?

Tags: reporting-services, rdlc, rdl

I have a SSRS report with a Tablix and 10 columns. Last column has it's visibility set to an expression, which hides it depending on report parameter. When it is hidden, the 9th column expands width and takes up 10th column space. How can I make some other column to auto expand and fill up the space, instead of the last one?